# How can I get last redis error

Tags: redis, servicestack

I tried to implement Truncate extension for ServiceStack Redis client..

```
 public void Truncate<T>()
    {
        using (var r = RedisManager.GetClient().As<T>())
        {
            r.DeleteAll();
        }
    }
```

But before truncate It must be delete and it does not work.
I can insert records one by one(so there is no problem with server)
So I want to debug..
I want to learn why I could not delete records? How can I get last error on server by ServiceStack RedisClient or else?

Ps: I'm using 64bit version of this: https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads

EDIT:
DeleteAll is  deleting only idx (autoincrementid) records :) Tricky.
But question is still. How can I get last error from redis server?